# name filter in popup menu in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, popupmenu

How can I add a popup menu in eclipse for two different kinds of file types using name filter.
I want the popup menu to be visible only for ".wsdl" and ".xsd" file types. I tried using

namefilter = "*.wsdl | *.xsd"

but it didn't work.

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namefilter uses `org.eclipse.ui.SelectionEnabler.verifyNameMatch(String, String)` to determine what's allowed.  It's a simple wildcard tester.  In [org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_popupMenus.html) you could potentially use visibility or enablement to provide more complex name choices.

You should also consider using [commands](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd.htm), and visibility there is controlled using the more flexible core expressions.

Comment: I used visibility inside my "ObjectContribution" element in element.                                                `<visibility>
            <or>
               <objectState
                     name="name"
                     value="*.wsdl">
               </objectState>
               <objectState
                     name="name"
                     value="*.xsd">
               </objectState>
            </or>
         </visibility>`